# Regex replace word in string if it is not a link

Tags: php, regex

I am using the following to find and replace words within string `$content`:

```
$replacedcontent = preg_replace('/\b'.$term_name.'\b/u', '<a class="highlight">'.$term_name.'</a>', $content);
```

Is there a simple way using regex to only replace words if they are not immediately preceded by an `<a href="[link to somewhere]">` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead assertion. This would replace all the `$term_name` which was not present inside the anchor tag.

```
preg_replace('/\b'.$term_name.'\b(?!(?:(?!<\/?a\b[^>]*>).)*?<\/a>)/u', '<a class="highlight">'.$term_name.'</a>', $content);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wJ5bG5/3)